# JQuery Drag and Drop Linking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make Jquery drag and drop app. I want to link each image to a droppable frame. I can't use IDs, so what is a better way to write it to check to see if they are the same?

EDIT: Here is the code

```
function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
        var slotNumber = $(this).attr('id');
        var cardNumber = ui.draggable.attr('id');
        var draggable = ui.draggable;
        if ( slotNumber == cardNumber ) {
            alert("Match" + slotNumber + cardNumber)
            ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
            $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
            ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
            ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );}
      }
```

As you can see, I can use ID to link them, but supposedly that is an extremely bad way to do it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please provide some sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question right, you probably want to use data attributes to distinguish the items. Here's an explanation of how data attributes work: [Data Attributes in HTML and jQuery](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/11/18/data-attributes-in-html-and-jquery/).